# Could not load file or assembly itextsharp

Tags: c#, winforms, installation, pdf-generation, itext

I had build setup file from my winform application. 
Then I installed it to my other computer, everything was working normally however when I clicked the `SaveToPDF` button which saves the gridview to pdf file

I encountered with this error :

> Could not load file or assembly itextsharp, Version = 4.1.6.15 , Culture=neutral, PublicKey Token=8354ae6d2174ddca'
>   or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

If I run application from visual studio everything works pretty good. 
Therefore while building the setup File iTextSharp content may be lost or while installing from setup iTextSharp content lost. 
I'm stuck with this problem and dont know how to fix. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right-click on iTextSharp and select Properties. Set "Copy Local" to True.

Also I'd recommend using NuGet for package management. If setting Copy Local doesn't work or if it's already set to true, remove the reference and using Package Manager Console enter this:

```
Install-Package iTextSharp
```

**UPDATE:**

I tried with the InstallShield 2015 trial. Here's my experience. I'm guessing it's pertinent to your problem:

I tried a Basic MSI project and in Application File I pointed the primary output of the project using iTextSharp assembly. When I built the project I got an error "-6213 - Internal Build Error" Apparently it's a known issue with the .NET projects. Here is their article suggesting a workaround: https://flexeracommunity.force.com/customer/articles/en_US/ERRDOC/Q109089

The suggestion is turning off Dependency Scanning at build. I did that and the project compiled fine. But when I installed it only the exe for the application was deployed and iTextSharp wasn't. So this may be your case. Do you recall disabling scanning dependencies?

I removed the Project Output and added the desired files manually. This time it gave another internal error but fixed it with their suggestion (replacing ISWIScanners.dll with a new one they provide and rebuild). This time I could get all the files I wanted deployed but of course it's not ideal.

I'd suggest adding the files manually and applying the workaround. Alternatively, you can give Wix (http://wixtoolset.org) a go - a free and open-source installer. I haven't used it myself but heard it on DotNetRocks podcast. It's free so it might be worth a shot.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: just to be sure, from visual studio I opened the project then opened the references from solution explorer and set the copy local to true right ?
Because I did it end still getting the same problem, by the way I used NuGet to install iTextSharp in the first place.

Comment: Hmm.. so you said you can build the project successfully, right? Could you please check the bin\Debug (or Release) folder to check if the iTextSharp DLL is there?

Comment: I'm sorry for ambuguity, there is no problem with debugging, when I debug program It runs pretty well however after I created a new project and builg a setup file via installshield wizard , in order to install my application to my other computer, I installed that winform application to my other computer, thats when I encountered with this error.
Edit: iTextSharp.dll is at the same location with winformApp.exe file

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I'll have a look again later and let you know if I can reproduce

Comment: Adding desired files manually did help, thanks for help, I'm accepting this as answer.

Comment: Installing iTextSharp with command "Install-Package iTextSharp" directly from Nuget Packager Manager console my issue. Thanks